# Handling “Accept Cookies” popup with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have been trying to scrape some information of this website with selenium. However when I access the website
it need to accept cookies to continue and it seems it is Java script.

Does anyone know how to get around this? or which topic should i focus on?

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://www.giffgaff.com")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am currently on android mobile so I can't use DevTools.

First you can right click the "Accept All cookies" button and Click Inspect and then copy the XPath.

Now try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,''))).click()
```

Replace the empty string with the XPath, or you can adjust the wait.

Answer (score 0):

To click on <kbd>Accept all cookies</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.giffgaff.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.cbot-btn__switch"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.giffgaff.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='trynow']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: giffgaff]